# blockchain unconfirmed and unspent output

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

sent btc to a miner for a mining contract, but while i was sending the btc, they timed out the offer.   Now my btc are sitting in limbo, pending transaction, unconfirmed and unspent.
4167a51abe68851d04733204ed069755224555075b72a89a70feccb2ad032efc

Any solution other than hope for blockchain to return it to my account?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) has general answers about unconfirmed transactions.

In your case, if the tx is confirmed, then you will have to communicate wit the counterparty (the miner) to ensure they fulfill their end of the transaction. If it does not confirm, your coins will become spendable again (see that thread for more info).